# Kali linux - Crontab @reboot is not executing

Tags: cron, kali-linux

I'm on Kali Linux with `VERSION_ID="2019.3"`

---

uname -a
`Linux kali 4.19.0-kali5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-6kali1 (2019-07-22) x86_64 GNU/LINUX`

---

Trying to execute `adjust_timezone.sh` placed in `/usr/local/startup_scripts/`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Adjusting timezone...";   
ntpdate in.pool.ntp.org;
```

The output of `which ntpdate`

```
/usr/sbin/ntpdate
```

I tried using the full path in the script too, no success.

---

The content of `/etc/crontab`

```
SHELL=/bin/sh  
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
@reboot /usr/local/startup_scripts/adjust_timezone.sh
```

---

Added the same using `crontab -e` too

```
@reboot /usr/local/startup_scripts/adjust_timezone.sh
```

---

I tried using `@reboot : /usr/local/startup_scripts/adjust_timezone.sh` too with no success.
I modified the script adding `2>&1 >> log.txt` but the log is empty, i think the script is never executing.

Where I'm wrong? Any advice?

---

**EDIT**
As suggested the logging format was wrong, i changed it in `>> /log.txt 2>&1` and here's the result :

```
/usr/local/startup_scripts/adjust_timezone.sh: 3: ntpdate: not found
Error resolving in.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
20 Aug 15:14:37 ntpdate[612]: Can't find host in.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
20 Aug 15:14:37 ntpdate[612]: no servers can be used, exiting
```

Comment: What happens if you run `/usr/sbin/ntpdate in.pool.ntp.org` directly? Same question, but for `/usr/local/startup_scripts/adjust_timezone.sh`?

Comment: Your `2>&1 >>log.txt` is wrong. Try `>>/tmp/log.txt 2>&1` (the order is important).

Comment: Is the script executable?

Comment: Running `/usr/sbin/ntpdate in.pool.ntp.org` i get the desired behavior, same result adding `/bin/sh` before. Yes you're right the log format is incorrect, and yes I made the script executable using  `chmod +x ...`

Comment: Did you run exactly `/usr/local/startup_scripts/adjust_timezone.sh` or did you add `/bin/sh` to the front of the command?

Comment: Yes i run that command and the script is executing correcting without adding /bin/sh... Anyway logging worked... posting the result ad edit in the question

Comment: Ah. Your `ntpdate` is running before your network's up.

Comment: Oh yes, ok... i'm modifying the script waiting for  the network up before executing the command :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `ntpdate` is running before the network is up and functional.

A better solution might be to use the `systemd` time synchronisation module rather than creating your own. Or install `ntpd` and let it manage your system's time.